# Stripe Portal PHP error - Class Not Found

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Trying to integrate Stripe Portal to my PHP website and this error keeps showing.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe_Util_Set' not found in

Comment: The error is clear: You don't have that class in your workspace. Don't you have to import it somehow? Please give us more information.

Comment: @bpanatta i used composer to get all the files

Comment: Then it is not being loaded by the composer. Can you share the `require` part of your composer.json?

Comment: @bpanatta 
{
    "require": {
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.67"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The `Stripe_Util_Set` class name is not used since stripe
/stripe-php [v2.0.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/commit/ac931109ab94f5b1ed10be8c8cb4e7cd9ff4b00d#diff-375b0771cd29da278907c1b4a3b9bdbf2877d10c8d6d4698758954998039a5bb).

Since you are using version `^7.67`, please update your code with a newer example reference. This class, for example, should be referenced as `\Stripe\Util\Set`.

Comment: There's a lot of things to change, can you please guide which older version of the APi should i use ?

Comment: They've updated that on `v2.0.0`, so anything on `v1.18.0` or before my help. I would update the code though, since legacy codes my contain security breaches.